# How to set an option as disabled on ng-select?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

Using ng-select version 12. Is there an option to set an item option as disabled ? ... they have a bunch of [samples](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates)  with some rows as disabled, but no explanation as to how they accomplish this. By checking the source code, I can see some of the data rows have an attribute as disabled:true ... I assumed all I had to do was to set this property to my objects, but still, not able to disable an item.

Comment: Can you make example on stackblitz?

Comment: Just add a property called `disabled` in your array of objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, adding `disabled:true` to the object you want to disable is correct.

The following code finds one person and disable him.

```
this.dataService.getPeople().subscribe((people) => {
      this.people = people;
      const p2 = this.people.find((p) => p.id === '5a15b13c728cd3f43cc0fe8a'); 
      p2.disabled = true;
    });
```

The following code finds all people whom isActive prop is false and disable them

```
 this.dataService.getPeople().subscribe((people) => {
      this.people = people.map((p) =>
        p.isActive ? p : { ...p, disabled: true }
      );
    });
```

Here is the [code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-disabled-r6cryb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks .... it actually worked. Looks like I was adding the disabled property too late for the ngoptions to grab it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `<ng-option>`, put a `[disabled]` attribute with some conditional in it.

**example**

```
<ng-option [value]="item.value" [disabled]="someFunction(item)">{{item.name}}</ng-option>
```